# In both years |OR| From both years?

Tags: prepositions, sentence

Years: 2003 and 2033

**(In both years/From both years)** North and South America had the highest number of people living in urban areas.

///
Please provide an explanation of your answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I would say:

> In both years, both North and South America had the highest number of people living in urban areas.

Comment: You can say "from 1990", "between 1990", "of 1990", "behind 1990", "instead of 1990", "out from behind 1990". You can use any preposition at all. If you always use "in" whenever you are referring to a year, you won't be speaking English.

Comment: I didn't mean that you couldn't use any other preposition anywhere else. What I meant was that in this context, you should use "in" because nothing else, in my opinion, fits in the sentence. I apologise for misleading answer.